# iOS - UIDocumentInteractionController and adding a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

So I have an idea for something just for fun I want to try and was wondering if someone could give some insight whether it would be possible or not.

Basically, I want to try and use a `UIDocumentInteractionController` and place a clear overlay view over top of that that would serve as sort of a drawing board.  Is this something feasible to do?  I think it would be cool to try and make it so the user could circle part of the document and put a post it note on there to leave feedback.

I just need to know if anyone knows whether or not it's possible to add a view on top of a `UIDocumentInteractionController` window?  Or perhaps there is a better solution?  I am not looking for anyone to do this for me, just conceptual ideas.  Any thoughts or feedback would be appreciated.  :D

EDIT:  I know how to do all the things like handle touch events, view animation, all of that sort of stuff.  I am just opening a conceptual question to the public kicking some ideas around...

Comment: You can using insertSubview:aboveSubview:  I wasn't sure if there is a way to access the docController's view, or anything similar...

Comment: any luck on this? iam searching for a similar approach, in theory iam thinking about accessing the gesture recognizers of the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a nice idea however I don't believe you can achieve what you're shooting for.

After presenting its user interface, a document interaction controller handles all interactions needed to support file preview and menu display.

Comment: Yeah I realize that.  But I was wondering if you could insert a subview or something.  But it doesn't look like it.  I have an idea of using a modal view controller and present it over the document.  Not really sure how the Document controller will respond.  Would be interesting though...